# Implement a GPIO function with a callback calling a asyncio method

Tags: gpio, python

I am testing a sensor attached to the GPIO in raspberry using python 3.5. The idea is something similar to this [link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=141520&p=937599).

My code is:

```
gpio.add_event_detect(4, gpio.RISING, callback=lambda x: self.motion_sensor(message_manager_f), bouncetime=500)

def motion_sensor(self, message_manager_f):
            asyncio.async(message_manager_f("Motion detected!"))
```

Where `message_manager_f` is a callback to a function that process the string message. This callback can have a complex operation (i.e. send to a server an alert) and therefore I am trying to perform an asyncio operation.

If I run this code, when the sensor detects a presence, I have this error:

```
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Dummy-4'.
```

If I remove the asyncio operator, and for example I only print the message to console, it works fine as the example of the previous link. Of course, I have tried to search for this error in the web (python is not my strongest language) but nothing that helps me to explain this error (only a few entries with this issue). I am wandering if maybe mixing `gpio.add_event_detect` with a function that uses `asyncio` is not possible, but I have no idea where to check it.

Is it is possible to achieve what I want? If it is, can somebody explain what really means the obtained error and how to solve it?

The complete code is available in this [link](https://github.com/jorgehortelano/RedOwl/blob/master/RedOwl/sensors/sensors.py) if somebody thinks that the error can be elsewhere.

**--EDIT--**

Seems that same behavior is obtained with the next code:

```
self._message_manager = message_manager_f
gpio.add_event_detect(4, gpio.RISING, self.motion_sensor, bouncetime=500)

def motion_sensor(self):
    asyncio.async(self._message_manager("Motion detected!"))
```

Obviously, is related to the `asyncio.async`.

Comment: Since this seems to be more a Python asyncio issue than a Pi issue, you may have better luck getting a response if you post on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).  I assume you've already looked through the Python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html).

Comment: Yes, I also have thought to post it into Stackoverflow. But the library is related to raspberry directly. Also, I do not want to create a duplicated question in two different sites. And yes, before this I have take a look into the documentation of python and GPIO library, but my knowledge is not enought to understand the last one.

Comment: You may consider using gpio sysfs interface with asyncio, so you won't have to delve into threading stuff. See twisted example here: https://github.com/sardok/txgpio. Easily convertible to asyncio.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, I agree with @thephez that this question is probably better for stackoverflow. Since there is a overlap with the `RPI.GPIO`, I have taken the liberty to answer it the best I can.

## Part 1 - RPI.GPIO

To really understand how the callback mechanism is implemented/works in RPI.GPIO, I dug into its
[source code](https://pypi.python.org/packages/c1/a8/de92cf6d04376f541ce250de420f4fe7cbb2b32a7128929a600bc89aede5/RPi.GPIO-0.6.2.tar.gz#md5=9db86fd5f3bae872de9dbb068ee0b096)

Within it there is a file `event_gpio.c` and between lines 430 through 480 I found 
the definition of the function `add_edge_detect` Within this function a background 
thread is launched using `pthread_create` which essentially blocks until some 
interesting GPIO pin transition happens. When such an event occurs, the thread 
unblocks and executes the collection of callbacks registered.

```
int add_edge_detect(unsigned int gpio, unsigned int edge, int bouncetime)
// return values:
// 0 - Success
// 1 - Edge detection already added
// 2 - Other error
{
    // <<< snip >>>

    // start poll thread if it is not already running
    if (!thread_running) {
        if (pthread_create(&threads, NULL, poll_thread, (void *)t) != 0) {
           remove_edge_detect(gpio);
           return 2;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

## Part 2 - Python asyncio

Consider the simple async example [here](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#event-loop-examples)

```
import asyncio

def hello_world(loop):
    print('Hello World')
    loop.stop()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

# Schedule a call to hello_world()
loop.call_soon(hello_world, loop)

# Blocking call interrupted by loop.stop()
loop.run_forever()
loop.close()
```

When a python process starts, there is by default 1 thread that executes the python code.
In the above example one can see there is a blocking call to `loop.run_forever()`.
Internally it would wait for some `task` to be submitted (execute `hello_world` in this case)
into a priority queue and execute accordingly.

To verify this, we need to peek a bit under the hood. From the [source code](https://pypi.python.org/packages/da/54/054bafaf2c0fb8473d423743e191fcdf49b2c1fd5e9af3524efbe097bafd/asyncio-3.4.3.tar.gz#md5=a189813096a6da1e46c16a41edb5f96d) of `loop.run_forever` in `base_events.py` one can see it simply keeps calling `_run_once()` in a loop

```
def run_forever(self):
    """Run until stop() is called."""
    self._check_closed()
    if self.is_running():
        raise RuntimeError('Event loop is running.')
    self._thread_id = threading.get_ident()
    try:
        while True:
            try:
                self._run_once()
            except _StopError:
                break
    finally:
        self._thread_id = None
```

`_run_once` is implemented like so using a heap (priority queue)

```
def _run_once(self):
"""Run one full iteration of the event loop.

This calls all currently ready callbacks, polls for I/O,
schedules the resulting callbacks, and finally schedules
'call_later' callbacks.
"""

sched_count = len(self._scheduled)
if (sched_count > _MIN_SCHEDULED_TIMER_HANDLES and
    self._timer_cancelled_count / sched_count >
        _MIN_CANCELLED_TIMER_HANDLES_FRACTION):
    # Remove delayed calls that were cancelled if their number
    # is too high
    new_scheduled = []
    for handle in self._scheduled:
        if handle._cancelled:
            handle._scheduled = False
        else:
            new_scheduled.append(handle)

    heapq.heapify(new_scheduled)
    self._scheduled = new_scheduled
    self._timer_cancelled_count = 0
else:
    # Remove delayed calls that were cancelled from head of queue.
    while self._scheduled and self._scheduled[0]._cancelled:
        self._timer_cancelled_count -= 1
        handle = heapq.heappop(self._scheduled)
        handle._scheduled = False

timeout = None
if self._ready:
    timeout = 0
elif self._scheduled:
    # Compute the desired timeout.
    when = self._scheduled[0]._when
    timeout = max(0, when - self.time())

if self._debug and timeout != 0:
    t0 = self.time()
    event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
    dt = self.time() - t0
    if dt >= 1.0:
        level = logging.INFO
    else:
        level = logging.DEBUG
    nevent = len(event_list)
    if timeout is None:
        logger.log(level, 'poll took %.3f ms: %s events',
                   dt * 1e3, nevent)
    elif nevent:
        logger.log(level,
                   'poll %.3f ms took %.3f ms: %s events',
                   timeout * 1e3, dt * 1e3, nevent)
    elif dt >= 1.0:
        logger.log(level,
                   'poll %.3f ms took %.3f ms: timeout',
                   timeout * 1e3, dt * 1e3)
else:
    event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
self._process_events(event_list)

# Handle 'later' callbacks that are ready.
end_time = self.time() + self._clock_resolution
while self._scheduled:
    handle = self._scheduled[0]
    if handle._when >= end_time:
        break
    handle = heapq.heappop(self._scheduled)
    handle._scheduled = False
    self._ready.append(handle)

# This is the only place where callbacks are actually *called*.
# All other places just add them to ready.
# Note: We run all currently scheduled callbacks, but not any
# callbacks scheduled by callbacks run this time around --
# they will be run the next time (after another I/O poll).
# Use an idiom that is thread-safe without using locks.
ntodo = len(self._ready)
for i in range(ntodo):
    handle = self._ready.popleft()
    if handle._cancelled:
        continue
    if self._debug:
        try:
            self._current_handle = handle
            t0 = self.time()
            handle._run()
            dt = self.time() - t0
            if dt >= self.slow_callback_duration:
                logger.warning('Executing %s took %.3f seconds',
                               _format_handle(handle), dt)
        finally:
            self._current_handle = None
    else:
        handle._run()
handle = None  # Needed to break cycles when an exception occurs.
```

## Part 3

Explaining the error you are getting

> `RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Dummy-4'.`

This would be because the thread 'Dummy-4' is the thread described in Part 1 which 
executes the GPIO callbacks. As there is no `loop` object created on this thread; 
there is no `loop.run_forever()` that is required to service your `message_manager_f` callback

## Part 4

How to fix this problem ?

Simply introducing a event loop within your `def motion_sensor` is **not** 
the right way to do it

```
def motion_sensor(self, message_manager_f):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.call_soon(message_manager_f, loop)
    loop.run_forever()
    loop.close()
```

This wrong is because

- the call wouldnt really be async with respect to the GPIO callback thread
- this will block the RPI.GPIO's thread from servicing other callbacks

My solution would look something like this

```
import asyncio
import RPIO.GPIO as GPIO
import sys

loop = None

def message_manager_f():
    print ":P message_manager_f()"

def motion_sensor(self, message_manager_f):
    if loop is None:
        print(":(")
        return       # should not come to this
    # this enqueues a call to message_manager_f() 
    loop.call_soon_threadsafe(message_manager_f)

# this is the primary thread mentioned in Part 2
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        # setup the GPIO
        GPIO.setwarnings(True)
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN) # adjust the PULL UP/PULL DOWN as applicable
        GPIO.add_event_detect(4, GPIO.RISING, callback=lambda x: self.motion_sensor(message_manager_f), bouncetime=500)

        # run the event loop
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_forever()
        loop.close()
    except :
        print("Error:", sys.exc_info()[0])

    # cleanup
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

## References

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586794/submit-a-job-to-an-asyncio-event-loop
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#asyncio-multithreading

## Notes

- As I don't have the required h/w handy, I haven't had a chance to verify the above code works correctly or not.
- Any errors or questions, please leave a comment and I will try to address it the best I can

Comment: Really good explanation that points out how far I am from understanding all python tricks. Thanks for all your effort. This weekend I will try to deeply understand your proposal and test it with my raspberry. But your explanation looks really good. I am agree that the question can be also in stackoverflow due to seems a python issue, not a GPIO issue. But seems that is not need to duplicate the question now.

Comment: Ok, I have found a few minutes to try your proposal. My `Dummy-4 loop error` has disappear. Still I have an error that is `TypeError: coroutines cannot be used with call_soon()`. In this case, I have added `@asyncio.coroutine` to the `message_manager_f` functions, and this error has disappeared. But now, `RuntimeError('Event loop is running.')` error is shown. Of course if I comment `loop.run_forever()` no any other error appear, but the message is never shown (neither a `prinf`).  We are close, but I need probably to expend more time with this code.

Comment: I just searched through the [source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/asyncio/) code of asyncio for 'Event loop is running' and found the only place such an error is raised is when of [`BaseEventLoop.run_forever()`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#l396) validates its inputs and current state; which would indicate there is another direct or indirect call to it somewhere in your script.

Comment: I will take a look on it. I have several dependencies and also can be there.

Comment: Ok, I have seen the code of `asyncio` you have pointed out, and you must be correct. Searching in my code, I am not using the function `run_forever()` but I am using `loop.run_until_complete()`. This is used for example, for establishing a connection with a [hangouts server](https://github.com/tdryer/hangups/blob/master/examples/send_message.py).

Comment: Seems that now it is working. Thanks again for your dedication.

Answer (score 6):

RPi.GPIO callbacks are run on a callback thread that is not the main thread.  asyncio event loops are associated with particular threads, and `asyncio.async` can only be used on a thread with an associated event loop.  In order to get from the RPi.GPIO thread back to the asyncio event loop thread, you've got to use `call_soon_threadsafe` on the asyncio loop object.  In order to do this, you must have a reference to the loop object obtained by calling `get_event_loop` on the asyncio thread.  (**Not** on the RPi.GPIO thread.)

Here is an example of combining RPi.GPIO and asyncio.  I have tested it on my Raspberry Pi by connecting a jumper cable between pins 16 and 22, which will allow it to send a signal from one pin to another, which will call the callback, and allow the queueing of the stop_loop coroutine in response to the GPIO event.

```
import asyncio
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

LOOP_IN = 16
LOOP_OUT = 22

@asyncio.coroutine
def delayed_raise_signal():
    yield from asyncio.sleep(1)

    GPIO.output(LOOP_OUT, GPIO.HIGH)

@asyncio.coroutine
def stop_loop():
    yield from asyncio.sleep(1)

    print('Stopping Event Loop')
    asyncio.get_event_loop().stop()

def gpio_event_on_loop_thread():
    asyncio.async(stop_loop())

def setup():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(LOOP_IN, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.setup(LOOP_OUT, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(LOOP_OUT, GPIO.LOW)

    def on_gpio_event(channel):
        print('Rising event detected')
        loop.call_soon_threadsafe(gpio_event_on_loop_thread)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    GPIO.add_event_detect(LOOP_IN, GPIO.RISING, callback=on_gpio_event)

    asyncio.async(delayed_raise_signal())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup()
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code looks promising! seems that `call_soon_threadsafe` is what I am looking for. Let me test it in my raspberry in the next days.

Comment: I do not understand why you are calling `gpio_event_on_loop_thread` and not directly `asyncio.async(stop_loop())`. Does it has a scope?

Comment: It will not work to call asyncio.async on the GPIO thread because the event loop isn't associated with the GPIO thread.  `on_gpio_event` runs on the GPIO thread.  The purpose of `gpio_event_on_loop_thread` is to run on the main thread so that it can call `asyncio.async`.

Comment: In versions of Python since 3.5.1, I think you could use `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(stop_loop(), loop)` instead of `call_soon_threadsafe`.  I was testing with a 3.4 version of Python, so I didn't use that.

Comment: Your code has been really helpful, but as your answer is very similar to @Shreyas Murali, and you have answered later, I am obligated to give the reward to him. Still in some points, your code is really clear as a solution.